# Proper synonym for following in this context

Tags: synonyms

Which proper synonym for **following** can I use in this sentence since I do not want to use it twice in the same sentence:

> After the deploying the service provider code on the server, the **following**  URL links in the **following** classes (PostDat, ClearTabe, AvailableRoutes, and GetLLRD) must be changed.

Comment: It's not necessarily wrong to use the same word twice in a sentence.  Although as Brian Tompsett points out, you may not even need the first "following".

Answer (score 2):

In my view you do not need a synonym as the first use of the word is redundant. It should just read:

> After the deploying the service provider code on the server, the URL links in the **following** classes (PostDat, ClearTabe, AvailableRoutes, and GetLLRD) must be changed.

If this is not appropriate we need to see more context, to provided a more extensive re-writing suggestion.